# How can filter or exclude error fields in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, response

It is possible reduce error response in case of exception?

- my index -> aho_bas
- my call via curl -> curl -v "localhost:9200/aaho_bas/_search?filter_path=took"  (**I intentionallity typed wrong the url**)
- response I'm getting:
  {"error":"error_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception",etc...}]}

**I'm trying get only some fields**, like error.reason. I need can manipulate the error response structure.
It is possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because really no index exists in elastic.
Looking closely at your index and query

index name -> `aho_bas`
index name from your query-> `aaho_bas`

query: `curl -v "localhost:9200/aaho_bas/_search?filter_path=took`

Since no index exists with that name, which is responsible for the origin of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solve: setting **http.detailed_errors.enabled:** false in elasticsearch.yml property file.
Doing this, in case of exception, the error response is:

{
   "error" : "IndexNotFoundException[no such index]",
   "status" : 404
}

that is a simpler response